# Obtener variable de shell desde C

Tags: c, linux, shell

Este es el código que estuve probando, pero por alguna razón la salida que obtengo es nada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc,char*argv[], char *envp[]){
    FILE *fp;
    char path[1035];
    fp=popen("/bin/echo ${COLUMNS}","r");
    if (fp==NULL){
        printf("hubo un error");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(path,sizeof(path)-1,fp)){
        printf("%s",path);
    }

    pclose(fp);
    return 0;

}
```

La pregunta es:

**¿Como hago para obtener la variable de shell $COLUMNS en lenguaje c, por linux?, o ¿Que me falta o estoy haciendo mal?**

Agradezco su interés

Answer (score 2):

Usa `getenv( )`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
  printf( "%s\n", getenv( "COLUMNS" ) );

  return 0;
}
```

`char *getenv( const char *name )` está disponible desde C89. Devuelve `NULL` si la variable en cuestión **no está** definida.

Observa que te devuelve un `char *`, que tendrás que convertir a lo que necesites; en tu caso, a un entero:

```
int ancho;
char *buff = getenv( "COLUMNS" );

if( buff )
  ancho = atoi( buff );
```